# KeyError: 'href' when using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a dataframe of article titles and links using BeautifulSoup from a website structured like this:

```
<div class = "publish date"> Article 1 published date </div>
<div class = "headline">
 <a href="article 1 link " target ="_blank" title="Opens in a new window"> Article 1 Title
 </a>
</div>

<div class = "publish date"> Article 2 published date</div>
<div class = "headline">
 <a href="article 2 link" target ="_blank" title="Opens in a new window"> Article 2 Title
 </a>
</div>
```

I was able to do this from a different webpage previously, but I am running into an error with this webpage.

My code:

```
r = requests.get(URL,allow_redirects=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    
tag = 'div'
title_class_name = "headline"


df = pd.DataFrame()
title_list = []
link_list=[]

title_table = soup.findAll(tag,attrs= {'class':title_class_name})
link_table = soup.findAll(tag,attrs= {'class':title_class_name})

for (title, link) in zip(title_table, link_table):
    title_list.append(title.text)
    link_list.append(link['href']) 
    df['title'] = title_list
    df['source'] = link_list
```

The only difference between the two is that the other website had a specific class within the a tags for the href links, but using `soup.findAll(tag,attrs= {'class':title_class_name})` does pull the a tag and the href link so I'm not sure why the line `link_list.append(link['href'])`  is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your selection strategy and process all information in one go:

```
data = []
for e in soup.select('.headline'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.text.strip(),
        'url':e.a.get('href')
    })
```

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div class = "publish date"> Article 1 published date </div>
<div class = "headline">
 <a href="article 1 link " target ="_blank" title="Opens in a new window"> Article 1 Title
 </a>
</div>

<div class = "publish date"> Article 2 published date</div>
<div class = "headline">
 <a href="article 2 link" target ="_blank" title="Opens in a new window"> Article 2 Title
 </a>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []
for e in soup.select('.headline'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.text.strip(),
        'url':e.a.get('href')
    })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | title | url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Article 1 Title | article 1 link |
| 1 | Article 2 Title | article 2 link |

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to using BeautifulSoup so I would not have though of that. I didn't realize how flexible it could be.